# Magento2 how to get upsell product on category listing page using object manager

Tags: category, up-sells

Note : First of all it is not good practice to use object manager directly on any file.use magento standard only

Below code is just to show that how we can easily get the upsell product on category listing page.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$categoryId = $category->getId();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    $current_product_id = $product->getId();
    $current_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($current_product_id);
    if ($current_product) {
    $upSellProducts = $current_product->getUpSellProducts();

    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
                $productId = $upSellProduct->getId();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
                echo 'Upsell Product name---'.$product->getName().'<br /><br/>';
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: it is a question Or Answer ?

Comment: i was suppose to ask question but after that i have debug and found solution so i have shared

Comment: OK, got it...  :)